# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Accounts#plans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

This is my route in Route file

```
get '/signup/:plan/:discount' =>'accounts#new', plan: nil, discount: 0, as: :new_account
```

And I am calling this routes in my html file like below

```
<a href="<%= new_account_url('$129', params[:discount]) %>" class="signup"><img src="/images/sign-up.png"></a>
```

After rake routes command run in back-end then I get following

```
 new_account GET    /signup/:plan/:discount(.:format)
   accounts#new {:plan=>nil, :discount=>0}
```

But I don't know what's wrong in the route that it's giving me error like

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts", :discount=>nil, :format=>nil, :plan=>"$129"} missing required keys: [:discount]
```

Comment: What is the value of `params[:discount]`?

Comment: Also try changing `discount: 0` to `discount: nil` in the route.

Comment: I also try with discount as nil but still not working . and params[:discount] is not compulsory when value comes then it's replace with nil or 0.

Comment: How are you getting the `params[:discount]`? I suspect the `params[:discount]` is not passed to the view.

Comment: But `plan: nil` doesn't make any sense.. may be `0` or some other default value makes more sense..

Comment: When you have no plan selected, your discount always will be `0`. Now when you have a plan, you may or may not have discount. I hope that is what is your business case. Confirm me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params[:discount]` is missing a value, hence when you call it in your routes, it's not being assigned:

```
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"accounts", :discount=>nil, :format=>nil, :plan=>"$129"}
```

Since you've made `:discount` a required part of the route, you need to pass a value to it when calling the helper.

---

The most important thing to do is to ensure your `params[:discount]` variable is populated. If not, you may wish to use [`bound parameters`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments#bound-parameters):

```
get '/signup/:plan(/:discount') =>'accounts#new', discount: 0, as: :new_account
```

This will make the `:discount` parameter non-essential.

---

As  a second, you should always use [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) whenever creating a link. It keeps your HTML up to date and in line with the specifications:

```
<%= link_to new_account_path("$129", params[:discount]), class: "signup" do %>
   <%= image_tag "sign-up.png" %>
<% end %>
```

-

You'll also want to make sure you're setting your routes within the bounds of their appropriate resources:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :accounts, only: [:new], path_names: { new: "signup" } do
   get ":plan(/:discount)", on: :new
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a url `'/signup/:plan/:discount'`, then `:plan` and `:discount` are both required key. You can never have values for those keys as `nil`. If you have, you will get always get the error you have right now.

As those values are optional, my suggestion will be to send them as a query param, and do a check inside the controller.

Try to reorganize the route definition :

```
get '/signup' =>'accounts#new', as: :new_account
```

You can also rewrite the url using `link_to` as below :

```
<%= link_to  new_account_path(plan: '$129', discount: params[:discount]), class: "signup" do %>
  <img src="/images/sign-up.png" />
<% end %>
```

Now, you will have always url like :

```
/signup?plain="xx"&discount="xx"
```